# Nginx PHP mbstring

Tags: php, centos, nginx, yum, php-cgi

I used this tutorial to install nginx on my Centos server http://moon.mastipoint.net/research/nginx-php-fpm-mysql-on-centos.html. I have everything running, however, I can't figure out how to install the php mbstring extension.

I've tried `yum install php-mbstring.i386` but it returns the following error:

```
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-mbstring.i386 0:5.1.6-27.el5_5.3 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: php-common = 5.1.6-27.el5_5.3 for package: php-mbstring
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
php-mbstring-5.1.6-27.el5_5.3.i386 from base has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: php-common = 5.1.6-27.el5_5.3 is needed by package php-mbstring-5.1.6-27.el5_5.3.i386 (base)
Error: Missing Dependency: php-common = 5.1.6-27.el5_5.3 is needed by package php-mbstring-5.1.6-27.el5_5.3.i386 (base)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script suggested by that blog post installs the [Webtatic](http://www.webtatic.com/) repo and uses it for its PHP packages. Try

```
yum --enablerepo=webtatic install php-mbstring
```